# При парсинге сайта выдаёт ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. На некоторых страницах нормально, на других, несмотря на схожесть, ошибка

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, lxml

При парсинге сайта на питоне выдаёт ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', но по какой-то причине это происходит только на страницах с номером больше 209(если номер меньше, всё нормально)

Никак не могу понять, почему? Эти "номерные" страницы сайта построены одинаково и всё должно работать.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

url = 'https://oge.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=209'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')


numtitle = soup.find('span', class_='prob_nums').text
awnser = soup.find('div', class_='solution').text
images = soup.find('div', class_='pbody').find_all('img')
soup = soup.find('div', class_='pbody').text


for image in images:
    src = image.get("src")
    if src:
        print(src)
for i in soup:
   soupn1 = soup.strip('&nbsp;')


for i in soupn1:
   soupn2 = soupn1.strip('&nbsp')

soupn3 = soupn2.replace('&nbsp',' ')

if 'Доказать' in soupn3 or 'доказать' or soupn3 or 'Докажите' in soupn3 or 'докажите' in soupn3:
  p=3
else:  
   awnser = awnser.partition('Ответ')[2]
   awnser = 'Ответ'+awnser
 
awnser = awnser.partition('Ответ')[2]
awnser = 'Ответ'+awnser
print(numtitle)
print(soupn3)
print(awnser)
```

Comment: Для кода 209 не может являться магическим числом. Никогда не парсил сайты, даже не очень знаю, что это, но логично предположить, что проблема в механизме работы сайта. Например, там ничего не должно подгружаться, чтобы вы могли по find забирать? Смотрите, чего конкретно не хватает, что объекта нет? Возможно, надо задержку внести какую-то, чтобы успевало подгрузиться.

Comment: @Сергей Задержка не помогает. Читал, что такая ошибка возможна из-за каких-то проблем у BeautifulSoup, но там ошибку он выдавал в любом случае, а у меня не работает на определённых страницах.

Comment: Задержка - просто пример. Начните  с того, чтобы увидеть - что именно не поступает вам? От этого и оттолкнитесь. Может, какие-то теги с 209й страницы отсуствуют и т.д.

Comment: @Сергей, спасибо, я идиот, не знал, что там на странице нет текста.

Comment: Вот видите:-) Я так и думал, что чтобы искать ошибки в парсинге, вообще не надо знать что это такое:-) На самом деле просто всегда надо тупо начинать с анализа ошибки и идти по ней.